# My domain cannot be resolved by DNS providers other than AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, routes, propagation

I changed my domain DNS provider to AWS Route 53 by creating a new Hosted Zone and passing name servers records to my domain. The problem is only AWS DNS provider can resolve my domain properly. When I try to resolve my domain  (using `nslookup`) by google DNS provider, for example (`8.8.4.4`), I get a different IP. Two days have passed since I changed the DNS provider. Is it possible that the propagation has not finished yet? Domain: `apploit.com`

Comment: can you share the real domain name (it would make troubleshooting easier)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added the real domain name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your [domain whois](http://whois.domaintools.com/apploit.com) (or query root servers) you will see that your name servers are set to:

```
apploit.com.    172800  IN  NS  ns2.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com.
apploit.com.    172800  IN  NS  ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com.
```

Quick googling says:

> If your domain name is suddenly not working and your name servers are
>   pointing to "ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com" it means that
>   your domain name has been suspended directly by the registry for
>   failing to verify your email address.
>
> ICANN mandates that new domain registrants verify their email address
>   within 15 days of purchasing a new domain name. Verification is
>   achieved by clicking an email link sent to the registered owner. If
>   you do not do this, your domain will be permanently suspended.
>
> To remove the suspension, simply find the verification mail and click
>   the link. The suspension is immediately removed once the verification
>   is successful, however, it may take some time for your name server
>   information to re-propagate through the entire internet.

Comment: You're right! I verified my domain. The name servers have changed but still other dns providers resolve my domain in wrong way. Is it just a propagation issue right now?